# WARN hdfs.DFSClient: zero

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am using Hadoop version 2.8.2, when I run some job on both master and slave, that use these files in hdfs. Both the master and the slaves show this below warning

```
17/11/15 12:51:46 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: zero
17/11/15 12:51:46 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: zero
17/11/15 12:51:46 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: zero
17/11/15 12:51:46 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: zero
17/11/15 12:51:46 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: zero
17/11/15 12:51:46 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: zero
```

How can i solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

It's OK
I guess each line means a new block is read